# Teradata get row counts for previous two days and compare

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to setup a data check, where we get the row count from a table for today and prior date.  Since it isn't loaded on weekends or holidays, I can't say DATE-1.

I came-up with the following, to get the previous date:

```
SELECT
LOAD_DATE
,COUNT(LOAD_DATE) RW_COUNT
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LOAD_DATE ) AS LOAD_ROWNUM
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1
WHERE LOAD_DATE >= DATE-6
GROUP BY 1
```

This produces the dates, counts and assigns a row number.

```
LOAD_DATE   RW_COUNT    LOAD_ROWNUM
2019-10-16  8259        1
2019-10-15  8253        2
2019-10-11  8256        3
2019-10-10  8243        4
```

I to take the two most current dates and compare them.  Most current would be "current" and the 2nd most current would be "prior" .  Then I would like to have something like this as the result set:

```
CURRENT_COUNT   PRIOR_COUNT DIFF_PERCENT
8259            8253        .9927
```

My issue is, how do I reference the first two rows and compare them to each other? Unless I'm over-thinking this, I need two additional SELECT statements: 1 with the WHERE clause referencing row 1 and another with a WHERE referercing row 2.

How do I do that?  Do I have two CTEs?
Eventually, I'll need a third SELECT dividing the two rows and checking for 10% tolerance.  Help, I'm in analysis paralysis.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Not clear what you are really trying to do, but you can just throw the output of your query into a volatile table.  Then you can do a self join, or maybe use lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the result of an OLAP-function using QUALIFY:

```
SELECT
   LOAD_DATE
  ,COUNT(LOAD_DATE) AS CURRENT_COUNT
   -- previous day's count
  ,LEAD(RW_COUNT)
   OVER (ORDER BY LOAD_DATE DESC) AS PRIOR_COUNT
-- if your TD version doesn't support LAG/LEAD (i.e. < 16.10)
--,MIN(RW_COUNT) 
-- OVER (ORDER BY LOAD_DATE DESC
--       ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS PRIOR_COUNT

   ,CAST(CURRENT_COUNT AS DECIMAL(18,4)) / PRIOR_COUNT AS DIFF_PERCENT
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1
WHERE LOAD_DATE >= DATE-6
GROUP BY 1
-- return the latest row only
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LOAD_DATE DESC) = 1
```

*checking for 10% tolerance*:

```
DIFF_PERCENT BETWEEN 0.9 and 1.1
```

Either ANDed to the QUALIFY or within a CASE

Comment: Perfect, thank you @dnoeth!
I with this: 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LOAD_DATE DESC) = 1 AND DIFF_PERCENT NOT BETWEEN 0.9 AND 1.1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want for your result set.  But you can use `LAG()` with aggregation to get the previous value.

```
SELECT LOAD_DATE, COUNT(*) as RW_COUNT,
       LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY LOAD_DATE) as PREV_RW_COUNT
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1
WHERE LOAD_DATE >= DATE-6
GROUP BY 1;
```

You may just want a difference of the two counts.

Answer (score 1):

If your `TD` version (16.0+?) doesn't support `LEAD/LAG`, give this a try:

```sql
SELECT 
  load_date, 
  RW_COUNT, 
  MAX(RW_COUNT) OVER(
    ORDER BY load_date DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING -- Get previous row's value
  ) AS RW_COUNT_prev
FROM (
  SELECT load_date, COUNT(LOAD_DATE) RW_COUNT,
  FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1
  WHERE LOAD_DATE >= DATE-6
  GROUP BY 1
) src
```